# Input 'b' of 'MatMul' Op has type float32 that does not match type float64 of argument 'a'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, typeerror

I've written a simple tensorflow code & constantly getting TypeError error, I am trying to write a code for simple log regression. Error is in this line : logits = tf.matmul( img,w) + b ,
Following is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 22, in <module> logits = tf.matmul(img,w) + b File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", 
    line 2122, in matmul a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py",
    line 4279, in mat_mul name=name) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", 
    line 546, in _apply_op_helper inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))
    TypeError: Input 'b' of 'MatMul' Op has type float32 that does not match type float64 of argument 'a'
```

Help me to resolve this issue. Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#making dummy dataset and converting that in tensor object
x = (np.random.sample((100,2)), np.random.sample((100,1)))
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
y = (np.random.sample((10,2)), np.random.sample((10,1)))
test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y)

#making iteration to access the dataset
train_iterator = train_data.make_initializable_iterator()
img, label = train_iterator.get_next()

#define weights & biases
w = tf.get_variable("weight", initializer=tf.constant((0.0)))
b = tf.get_variable("bias", initializer=tf.constant((0.0)))
tf.cast(img, tf.float64)
tf.cast(w, tf.float64)
tf.cast(b, tf.float64)

#model 
logits = tf.matmul(img,w) + b

#loss
entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=label, logits=logits)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy)

#optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(loss)


#create the session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(train_iterator.initializer)

    for i in range(100):
        sess.run([optimizer,loss])
    print(optimizer,loss)
```

Comment: Please include the full error stack, as well as *where* exactly in your code pops up...

Comment: logits = tf.matmul( img,w) + b  this line is showing the error.

Comment: Full error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    logits = tf.matmul(img,w) + b
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 2122, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 4279, in mat_mul
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 546, in _apply_op_helper
    inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))

Comment: Not in the comments - it is literally unreadable! Edit & update your post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not save the `tf.cast()` result back to the variables. Try below to fix it.

```
img = tf.cast(img, tf.float64)  
w = tf.cast(w, tf.float64)
b = tf.cast(b, tf.float64)
```